# How to get mobile Facebook login dialog on WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

Using Facebook C# SDK, 
I use GetLoginUrl with following parameters:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters["client_id"] = FacebookSettings.AppID;
parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
parameters["response_type"] = "token";
parameters["display"] = "page";
parameters["scope"] = ExtendedPermissions;
```

and render the response in a WebBrowser control. 
However, the response is a standard desktop web page, which is unsuitable for use in a cellphone. 
Howe would I go about getting the mobile login dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is explained very well [here](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx)

If you don't like using page, follow the directions in that blog post and it will do it for you.

> By default the display is set to page by Facebook, we overwrite it to popup so that it consumes less space. More information about the display mode can me found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display

Comment: Went with display="touch". Also useful was. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/